# Pause a loop on Linux

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, bash-scripting

I'm using the following code to loop `ffmpeg` on my Linux server.

This is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :; do
    ffmpeg -re -i "input" output.mp4
done
```

What I would like do to is pause the loop so it stops looping until I want to resume, acting as a 'off' and on 'switch' for the stream without having to reboot the server each time :)

Comment: Did you try `Ctrl+c` ?

Comment: nope, that will stop the loop until i run the .Sh file again?

Comment: Ohh, sorry, I misread your question then, I thought you want to stop it... but you need pause...

Comment: yeah i used ctrl + c and had to reboot my server before the loop worked again haha

Comment: Look into SIGSTOP and SIGCONT.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Press "s" to pause loop or Ctrl+c to stop'
n=1 
while true; do
    read -r -t 0.5 -n 1 -s stop
    [ -n "${stop}" ] && {
      read -p 'Paused... press Enter button for continue' x
    }

    ffmpeg -re -i "input" output.mp4

    n=$(( n+=1 ))
    echo "Loop Counter: ${n}"
done
```

Comment: so i use s to pause then s to resume or s to pause and x to resume?

Comment: ohh i see now use enter button to resume

Comment: @WEBX  Replace `ffmpeg -re -i "input" output.mp4` with `sleep 2; echo 'processing'` for the test purpose and let me know if it works for you